# How to display nested json data in React in key and value pair form?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

This is the product description component which has two tabs description and details. When we click on description tab, product specification will be displayed in tabular form. we use the Axios library to fetch JSON data from API.
I want to access the description object in the "key: value" format in the table.
Anyone help me to solve this kind of problem.

**details-top-tab.jsx:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel } from "react-tabs";
import "react-tabs/style/react-tabs.scss";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class DetailsTopTabs extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.item.description);
    const { item } = this.props;
    return (
      <section className="tab-product m-0">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
            <Tabs className="tab-content nav-material">
              <TabList className="nav nav-tabs nav-material">
                <Tab className="nav-item">
                  <span className="nav-link active">
                    <i className="icofont icofont-ui-home"></i>Description
                  </span>
                  <div className="material-border"></div>
                </Tab>
                <Tab className="nav-item">
                  <span className="nav-link">
                    <i className="icofont icofont-man-in-glasses"></i>Details
                  </span>
                  <div className="material-border"></div>
                </Tab>
                {/* <Tab className="nav-item">
                  <span className="nav-link">
                    <i className="icofont icofont-contacts"></i>Video
                  </span>
                  <div className="material-border"></div>
                </Tab>
                <Tab className="nav-item">
                  <span className="nav-link">
                    <i className="icofont icofont-contacts"></i>Write Review
                  </span>
                  <div className="material-border"></div>
                </Tab> */}
              </TabList>
              <TabPanel className="tab-pane fade mt-4 show active">
                <table className="table table-striped mb-0">
                  <tbody>
                    {item.description.map((item) => (
                      <tr>
                        <th>{item.name} </th>
                        <td>{item.value}</td>
                      </tr>
                    ))}
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </TabPanel>
              <TabPanel>
                <p className="mt-4 p-0">{item.shortDetails}</p>
              </TabPanel>
              {/* <TabPanel>
                <div className="mt-4 text-center">
                  <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe
                      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BUWzX78Ye_8"
                      allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
                      allowFullScreen
                    ></iframe>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </TabPanel>
              <TabPanel>
                <form className="theme-form mt-4">
                  <div className="form-row">
                    <div className="col-md-12 ">
                      <div className="media m-0">
                        <label>Rating</label>
                        <div className="media-body ml-3">
                          <div className="rating three-star">
                            <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="name"
                        placeholder="Enter Your name"
                        required
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="email"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        required
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                      <label htmlFor="review">Review Title</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="review"
                        placeholder="Enter your Review Subjects"
                        required
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                      <label htmlFor="review">Review Title</label>
                      <textarea
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Wrire Your Testimonial Here"
                        id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
                        rows="6"
                      ></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                      <button className="btn btn-solid" type="submit">
                        Submit YOur Review
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </TabPanel> */}
            </Tabs>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default DetailsTopTabs;
```

**Sample JSON Data:**

```
{
    "product": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Flare Dress",
        "price": 120,
        "salePrice": 200,
        "discount": 50,
        "pictures": [
          "/assets/images/fashion/product/1.jpg",
          "/assets/images/fashion/product/21.jpg",
          "/assets/images/fashion/product/36.jpg",
          "/assets/images/fashion/product/12.jpg"
        ],
        "shortDetails": "Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem,",
        "description": {
          "Ram": "4gb",
          "size": "large"
        },
        "stock": 16,
        "new": true,
        "sale": true,
        "category": "women",
        "colors": ["yellow", "gray", "green"],
        "size": ["M", "L", "XL"],
        "tags": ["nike", "caprese"],
        "rating": 4,
        "variants": [
          {
            "color": "yellow",
            "images": "/assets/images/fashion/product/1.jpg"
          },
          {
            "color": "gray",
            "images": "/assets/images/fashion/product/21.jpg"
          },
          {
            "color": "green",
            "images": "/assets/images/fashion/product/36.jpg"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)?

Comment: Nope, let me try!! Thanks for the solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel } from "react-tabs";
    import "react-tabs/style/react-tabs.scss";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

    class DetailsTopTabs extends Component {
      render() {
        console.log(this.props.item.description);
        const { item } = this.props;
        return (
          <section className="tab-product m-0">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                <Tabs className="tab-content nav-material">
                  <TabList className="nav nav-tabs nav-material">
                    <Tab className="nav-item">
                      <span className="nav-link active">
                        <i className="icofont icofont-ui-home"></i>Description
                      </span>
                      <div className="material-border"></div>
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab className="nav-item">
                      <span className="nav-link">
                        <i className="icofont icofont-man-in-glasses"></i>Details
                      </span>
                      <div className="material-border"></div>
                    </Tab>
                    {/* <Tab className="nav-item">
                      <span className="nav-link">
                        <i className="icofont icofont-contacts"></i>Video
                      </span>
                      <div className="material-border"></div>
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab className="nav-item">
                      <span className="nav-link">
                        <i className="icofont icofont-contacts"></i>Write Review
                      </span>
                      <div className="material-border"></div>
                    </Tab> */}
                  </TabList>
                  <TabPanel className="tab-pane fade mt-4 show active">


       <table className="table table-striped mb-0">
                  <tbody>
         -------------------------------------------------------------
                    {Object.entries(item.description).map((item) => (
                      <tr>
                        <th>{item[0]}</th>
                        <td>{item[1]}</td>
                      </tr>
                    ))}
       ---------------------------------------------------------------    
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </TabPanel>
              <TabPanel>
                <p className="mt-4 p-0">{item.shortDetails}</p>
              </TabPanel>
              {/* <TabPanel>
                <div className="mt-4 text-center">
                  <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe
                      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BUWzX78Ye_8"
                      allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
                      allowFullScreen
                    ></iframe>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </TabPanel>
              <TabPanel>
                <form className="theme-form mt-4">
                  <div className="form-row">
                    <div className="col-md-12 ">
                      <div className="media m-0">
                        <label>Rating</label>
                        <div className="media-body ml-3">
                          <div className="rating three-star">
                            <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="name"
                        placeholder="Enter Your name"
                        required
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="email"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        required
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                      <label htmlFor="review">Review Title</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="review"
                        placeholder="Enter your Review Subjects"
                        required
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                      <label htmlFor="review">Review Title</label>
                      <textarea
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Wrire Your Testimonial Here"
                        id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
                        rows="6"
                      ></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                      <button className="btn btn-solid" type="submit">
                        Submit YOur Review
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </TabPanel> */}
            </Tabs>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
    }
    }

    export default DetailsTopTabs;
```

Comment: Please explain the changes you have made and why with the answer

Comment: I suggest also using array destructuring to improve readability, i.e. `Object.entries(item.description).map(([key, value]) => (...`

Comment: Object.entries would give him a list of key-values from his description and he can directly map on them and use it as item[0] and item[1].I guess thats what he wants

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni Agney's point is more that a solution, working or not, without explanation isn't a very valuable answer.